# How to consume and produce different content-types but with same post mapping and parameters but different return types?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have two methods with same name, parameter and post mapping, only difference is the content type it consumes, produces and its return type.

But spring boot says method is already defined, so if I change the method name it works but not with the same method name.

Is there any way to use the same method name without causing ambiguity? I want to use the same api in my application, so the client can request it with different content-type in the request header

I am using JDK 17

```
@PostMapping(path = "/updateprofile/{username}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String updateProfile(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Profile profile) {
//        Profile updatedProfile = profileService.updateProfile(profile, username);
        System.out.println("Testing  " + profile);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/updateprofile/{username}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Profile updateProfile(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Profile profile) {
//        Profile updatedProfile = profileService.updateProfile(profile, username);
        System.out.println("Testing  " + profile);
        return profile;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not Spring Boot. It's a basic Java rule that method overloads need to have different input parameters.

Comment: Why do you care what the Java method name is?

Comment: @shmosel Just realised this now, its a basic java rule for method overload

Answer (score 0):

We can have same api path for multiple methods, methods with different signatures and clients will still talk with the same api endpoint.
We can accept different content-types in different methods having same or different logic but listening at the same api endpoint

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).